# How to send value of ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> from one to another activity

Tags: android-listview, arraylist, hashmap

**This is ListView**

```
<LinearLayout
   … >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and 3 item at the сell**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1" />
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2" />
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>
```

**This is code**

```
public class Spisok extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Irr;
    private static final String Form1 = "form1"; // Форма1
    private static final String Form2 = "form2"; // Форма2
    private static final String Form3 = "form3"; // Форма3

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spisok);
        setTitle("Irr");

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // создаем массив списков
        Irr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> hm;

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(Form1, "1");
        hm.put(Form2, "2");
        hm.put(Form3, "3");
        Irr.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(Form1, "1");
        hm.put(Form2, "2");
        hm.put(Form3, "3");
        Irr.add(hm);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, Irr,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { Form1, Form2, Form3 },
                new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, New.class);
    intent.putExtra("arraylist", Irr);
    startActivity
    }
});
```

**and this:**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)     getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");

    TextView Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text9);
    Info.setText("view" +Irr); }
```

**But it is work as wrong. When I use it, I have all ArrayList in the new Activity**

```
 intent.putExtra("arraylist", Irr);
```

**I need have only "hm.put(Form3, "3");" (correctly only "3" value) in my NewActivity.
Help me to consist it correctly.**

Comment: Whats your problem? Transfering data from one `Activity` to another? Or creating a new `Activity`?

Comment: "Transfering data from one Activity to another" It's problem. New activity have to have "text3" in accordance with botton at cell.

Comment: "something is wrong" is too vague. You have to describe your problem or show your error. Here is a description how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: There is not error. Just this is wrong: intent.putExtra ("form3", Form3 ); How to correcr put/get value?

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem ? It is not clear, just i considered that you have a Button in your Spisok Activity . so you need to create a `Button` object in your `noCreate()` method as like

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick (){
     Intent intent = new Intent (this, SecondActivity.class );
     startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

`SecondActivity.class` is your new Activity . you need to create this Activity class manually using IDE and also need to add this Activity in `Manefist` file. you can put your `TextView text3` SecondActivity's layout file .

Comment: Yes, but how should I do what my new activity consist of "text3" in accordance with pressed botton at the cell.

Comment: according to my answer . now if you press button1 then open second activity . and second activity has already a textview (text3). now do you want to show any information in text3 when user pressed button1 ?? please clear it

Comment: list: text1 text2 botton1 / text(1)3 text(2)4 botton1(2) /text(1)5 text(2)6 botton(1)3 / if I press botton1 should open new activity with "text2", if i press botton(1)3 -> open "text(2)6"

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the text of your R.id.text3 into your intent with the method [`putExtra(String key, String dataToTransfer)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Your `OnItemClickListener` could look like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, SecondActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra("key for my item 3", "put the text you want to transfer here")
    startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

And in the new Activity you get the transfered data like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String transferedText = intent.getStringExtra("key for my item 3");
}
```

Comment: please don't put code into comments! Update your question with the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom ListView ( without coustom listview you cant manage more items in single row), in every row there are two text view and one button. you want if user click the button then open new activity that shows second textview

In your adapter class's getView() method write this code

```
   @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{ 
View row = convertView;
Button button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
TextView text1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
TextView text2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
 deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent (this, SecondActivity.class );
              String text = text2.getText().toString();
               intent.putExtra("name", "text");                   
              startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });

}
```

and SecondActivity write this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intent);
    Textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    Intent iin= getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String j =(String) b.get("name");
        Textv.setText(j);
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: Sorry i was busy with other task.